# В чем разница между определениями: контейнер, коллекция и структура данных в Python?

Tags: python-3.x, коллекции, containers

Я учу Python. Знаю что существуют типы данных, и что каждый тип из себя представляет. Понимаю что есть структуры данных, это программные единицы которые могут содержать в себе другие данные и они одновременно являются типами тоже. Но в разных источниках, информация по-разному дается. И не понимаю в чем разница между коллекциями, структурами и контейнерами. Все они содержат те же list, dict, set, tuple, frozenset, по крайней мере если не использовать другие зависимости... Когда нужно использовать определение контейнер, структуру или коллекцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, навскидку:

- `контейнер`: **объект, содержащий в себе другие объекты**, причём тут нет никаких других условий - что это за объекты, упорядочены ли они как-то, просто объект с другими объектами внутри
- `структура`: **объект, имеющий чётко обозначенный (структурированный) список полей** (объектов) внутри себя, т.е. можно сказать, что это контейнер, но с неким структурированным (тут надо бы подобрать синоним, но что-то не придумаю) содержимым
- `коллекция`: **упорядоченный тем или иным способом набор объектов**, который мы можем перебирать некоторым стандартным способом (например, с помощью цикла `for`), по сути это опять же снова контейнер, и даже можно сказать структура с определёнными свойствами

Comment: по поводу встроенных коллекций можно сказать, что это те же структуры данных, но еще включающие строку)? так как строка тоже итерируемый объект) структуры же данных и контейнеры это одно и тоже определение, в них те же list, dict, set и tuple)

Comment: @asphyxia22 Строка - это с одной стороны коллекция символов, а с другой стороны всё же у строки много других признаков, это отдельная всё же сущность, хотя её можно и как коллекцию рассматривать, но это не главное в ней.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказал так:

Термин "структура данных" используют, когда говорят о некотором типе данных, имеющем сложное внутреннее устройство именно в контексте того, как оно устроено. При этом вообще не обязательно, чтобы этот тип данных мог вмещать в себя другие типы данных.

Термин "контейнер" подразумевает именно то, что внутри объекта содержатся другие объекты. При этом не обязательно их может быть боьше одного, и они не обязательно однотипные.

Термин "коллекция" подразумевает объект, который вмещает в себя именно множество других объектов (обычно - однотипных) и предоставляет возможность работы с содержимым именно как с неким множеством элементов, которые можно обрабатывать однотипно. Например, коллекция почти всегда подразумевает возможность итерации по содержимому.

Comment: спасибо) думаю чтобы окончательно разобраться, эти топики надо смотреть в оригинале на английском, и делать выводы там)